# What theme works well for both GTK2 and GTK3 applications?

Tags: debian, lxde, theme, gtk3, gtk2

I've installed Debian Wheezy, with the LXDE desktop environment. The default Clearlooks theme is fine, but it doesn't work for gtk3 apps (like Transmission).

Which theme can I use, so that both gtk2 and gtk3 apps will look normal?

Comment: Just curious but why are you asking very similar questions? I saw http://askubuntu.com/questions/397711/lxde-theme-that-works-for-both-gtk2-and-gtk3 posted around the same time.

Comment: Because my question is about Debian, but I remember having the same problem in Ubuntu a long time ago, too. Currently the problem is for Debian, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to find a theme that works - [Ambiance from Ubuntu Precise](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/light-themes_0.1.9.1-0ubuntu1.tar.gz). Newer themes will not work for gtk3 apps.

All you need to do is extract the archive and copy the Ambiance folder to `/usr/share/themes`, then select it from `lxappearance`.

Answer (score 0):

**Clearlooks**

One option is to install the [clearlooks-phenix-theme](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/clearlooks-phenix-theme) package for Debian Squeeze. This provides themes for GTK2, GTK3, XFce4, Metacity and Openbox.

[image]